# Averaging a column based on two other columns

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame with four columns. For every match in column 2 and 3, I would like to average the value in column 4 and store this in a new data frame.

New to pandas, so not sure how to proceed on this. Any guidance is greatly appreciated!

Eg:

Input:

```
2017 1 1 100
2016 1 1 200
2017 1 3 50
2016 1 3 100
```

Output

```
1 1 150
1 3 75
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby()` and then `mean()` will do the trick

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,1], 'b':[1,1,3,3], 'c':[100,200,50,100]})
print(d)
   a  b    c
0  1  1  100
1  1  1  200
2  1  3   50
3  1  3  100
d.groupby(['a','b']).mean()
       c
a b     
1 1  150
  3   75
```

Comment: Great! Can I un-group afterwards to get full entries in the first column ?

Comment: Figured this out: need to use reset_index()